# Setup test data with UIAutomation

Tags: objective-c, ios, tdd, bdd, ios-ui-automation

Is it possible to setup test data when running UIAutomation tests for iOS?

I've seen some post that suggests you have uiautomation go through the UI to create the test data, but that seems like a generally bad approach to me.

Besides, my particular application is supposed to be getting all its data from the music library so it's seems like the only way to use test data would be to run the tests on a device with music on it.

Preferably there would be a way to use one of the mocking libraries to create some mock objects but I don't think UIAutomation can interact with the application at that level.

Answer (score 2):

I have all my tests broken into two stages: setup and test.  The setup stage is its own UIAutomation test that makes no assertions.  It just puts the simulator into the correct state.  After that test finishes, I copy the simulator directory (~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0) and save that for subsequent runs.  Then, before I run my test stage, I restore that saved simulator state.  That way, I only have to run my setup once.  Eventually, I'd like to open source my test runner.